# Another option to double pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, double-pointer

How could I send a pointer to a function with reference? I mean, I would like to change where the pointer is poiting in that function.

I have seen for this the double pointer, like for example:

```
Abc* p;
function(&p);

function(Abc** p){
  (*p) = 0;
}
```

But, I have been told that this is not the best way to approach it. How could be better? Would this work? :

```
Abc* p;
function(p);

function(Abc* p){
  p = 0;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Complete tutorial on passing a pointer by reference - pass it by reference `function(Abc*& p)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that will not work. That will copy the value of `p` into the function and then only modify that copy.

The most appropriate way to pass something by reference in C++ is to use a reference type. They are denoted with an ampersand in the type. You could take a reference to pointer:

```
Abc* p;
function(p);

void function(Abc*& p){
  p = 0;
}
```

This means that, even though you passed `p` directly, it is *not* copied into the function. The `p` argument is a *reference* to the object passed in.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I didn't know you could use both * and &. So it makes sense.